# What will be the Context for DBManagement class

Tags: android, sqlite

I am making CountDownTimer for which on time reach i can delete all my database. but when i make object of DBManagment class the context problem ahead. Kindly tell me what will be the context? In log the error showing "null".

the context needs for this line **dbManagement = new DBManagement();**

- the Timer class is non activity class

  private Context context;

  ```
  public Timer(long startTime, long interval)
  {
      super(startTime, interval);
  }

  @Override
  public void onFinish()
  {
      try {
          dbManagement = new `DBManagement(context.getApplicationContext());`
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.d("errorrrrrrrrr", " is " + e.getMessage());
      }

  }
  ```

the DBManagement class consist for following constructor:

```
// Constructor for creating database

public DBManagement(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

Calling Activity:

```
public class Blocklist extends AppCompatActivity {
private final long startTime = 1000;
    private final long interval = 1000;
    private Timer countDownTimer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_blocklist);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

// Count down timer
        countDownTimer = new Timer(startTime, interval);
        countDownTimer.start();
}
```

Comment: post you full code ?

Comment: still not complete post ur complet code of ur Activity Class

Comment: The context should probably be the calling activity, dunno without the full code

Comment: DBManagement class is also non activity class

Comment: public Timer(long startTime, long interval,Context context)
{
    super(startTime, interval,context);
}

Comment: countDownTimer = new Timer(startTime, interval,BlockList.this); try like this

Comment: and let me know is this working >/

Comment: super(startTime, interval, context); showing error (CountDownTimer in CountDownTimer cannot be applied to Expected queal and parameters arguments)

Comment: this work for me " this.context = context; " thanks for your help

Comment: please reply as a answer so i can accept your answer

Comment: see my answer below :) @bc120201817ZohaibSiddiq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

```
this.context =  context ;
```

and use this context in BD `constructor`

Hope it will helps you.